# How to capture flash events outside the swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to know if flash events (say clicking a button) can be captured somewhere outside the swf. Say, I click on a button and a popup comes up telling which buttom was clicked. The popup should not be a part of swf.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Im doubtful it can be done this way round but Javascript can call into a a Flash application to cause an event such as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

In your javascript:

```
function sayClicked(whatWasClicked) {
   alert(whatWasClicked);
}
```

in ActionScript:

```
protected function onButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
   ExternalInterface.call('sayClicked', (e.target as MovieClip).name);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
But i have a standalone swf (not embedded in javascript). Then how can i capture flash event outside swf.

Comment: @parve where exactly are you planning to "catch" flash events outside the swf?

Comment: What kind of application are you embedding the swf in?

Comment: For example startDrag a mc and releae outside the window containing the swf

Answer (score 0):

ok your short answer is you cant, flash is only limited to its own  movie, anything outside this movie, object can only be detected from another language such as java, php.
So by stand alone im assuming just a swf on a html page or just a pop out advertisement.

But it is possible to trace the mouse when it leaves the flash movie area,again it is  detecting that there is no mouse in the flash movie area, its not detecting the mouses position on the rest of the screen to say, or web browser.